# jquery From Plugin: file upload, then read directory but afterSuccess option too early

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to have users upload their files to my website. With the plugin it is very easy to display a progress bar which is why I am using it.

```
var options = { 
        target:   '#upload_output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback
        uploadProgress: OnProgress,
        success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
        resetForm: true               // reset the form after successful submit 
    }; 

 $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);            
        // return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation
        return false; 
    });
```

The HTML form tags looks like this

```
<form action="upload.php" onSubmit="return false" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
```

The upload.php file contains this

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fUpload']['tmp'], $upfile)) {
    echo "Upload complete.\n";
    // rename file to original
    rename($updir . basename($_FILES['fUpload']['tmp']), $updir . $_FILES['fUpload']['newname']);
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong\n";
}
```

What I like to do:
On the page where the user uploads his files there is also a div container showing all the files he has in his directory. This is filled in with a php script reading the files from outside the web root and triggered on site load.

What I can't figure out:
How do I update my div containing all files after the upload? The "target" option I need to display if the upload was successful or something went wrong. The "success" option (here function afterSuccess) triggers after the submit was sent, but does NOT wait for the upload to complete, i.e. it then loads the directory without the new file.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: According to the docs of the plugin the success: part does wait for the server response 
    Callback function to be invoked after the form has been submitted. If a 'success' callback function is provided it is invoked after the response has been returned from the server.

Comment: took that excerpt from http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object

Comment: You need to check if the file finished uploading using the function file_exists(), once it did show success message

Comment: @Brett: I assume the server responda that the submit was successful. If I include my directory scan after the echo("Upload complete"); within upload.php the result is correct, but I can't update the div from within upload.php

Comment: @Tom: once the "Upload complete" shows the file is available. Problem is I can't update the div from within the upload.php. If I place my dir scan routine there it "finds" the new file. Placing the same routine in the afterSuccess function of ajaxSubmit does not show the new file. I therefore suspect the afterSuccess triggers before upload.php is finished, maybe triggers on successful form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
  success: function(data){ $('#changedivid').text(data;}
```

Comment: Tom, why did you delete your XML question? I almost have the answer. Did you get an answer already or just can't wait? Actually, I just got the answer right now, but there is no question anymore :( . I guess you can post another question :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize someone was on it, I'll ask again THANK YOU!